# DblClick Cell text cursor blinking

Tags: vba, excel, cursor, cell

I have cell with value of string type. I programmed a `Public Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)` procedure to show UserForm after doubleclick on some cell - let it is "**B3**" cell. The UserForms is showed after doubleclick but there is **blinking text cursor** somewhere in middle of string of the doubleclicked "**B3**" cell. As a result I can't work with UsetForm buttons until I click to any other cell because blinking "B3" cursor locks it. After this click the "B3" unlocks and I can continue in my work.

My question: How can I in VBA **clear the blinking text cursor** in the active cell? I want to save the "B3" selection. It means the same situation like after single click on some other cell and then single click on the "B3" cell again.

Comment: You need to set the `Cancel` argument to True if you want to prevent the double-clicked cell going into edit mode.